# casting and parsing between string, object and int

Tags: c#, .net, casting

`ddlSomeDropDownType.SelectedValue` is a dropdown of `.aspx` page.
I have the following code:

```
int num = int.Parse(((object)this.ddlSomeDropDownType.SelectedValue).ToString());
```

Am I correct in thinking that the following happens:

1. Drop down value (string) gets down-casted to object
2. Object is a reference type so `.ToString()` doesn't do anything in this instance, gets omitted by the compiler
3. Object then gets parsed to int: ref type => value type

Or would the C# compiler pick up on that, and not cast when it doesn't have to?

Comment: Can't answer the question without knowing the type of `ddlDiscountType`

Comment: Also step #3 is clearly wrong, you have no "cast" to `int`.  Casting and parsing are completely different operations.

Comment: I would believe that the answer to 2 is that the `String` class' override of `Object.ToString()` gets called which just returns `this`.

Comment: Some information about [`Object.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) which you may find useful

Comment: What makes you think that `ToString` doesn't do anything because it is a reference type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> drop down value (string) gets down-casted to object

Well, yes, but all that changes is how subsequent calls to the object are bound by the compiler.  You're telling the compiler "treat this value as an `object`" It does not change the actual object in any way.

> object is a reference type so `.ToString()` doesn't do anything in this instance, gets omitted by compiler

No - you call `ToString` which is a virtual method on `object`, so either `object.ToString` or a subsequent override will get called (in your case, string.ToString()`.

Plus, you've told the compiler to treat the value as an `object`.  You expect the compiler to go back and say "well, I know you told me to treat it as an object, but I can tell from the code above that it's a string, so I'm going to ignore that and just keep it as a string".  The compiler will not go to that effort.  The JIT optimizer *may* do something similar if there is an iron-clad guarantee that it will work; otherwise it will do what you told it to do.

> object than gets cast to int

No - it is *parsed* by the `int` class - very different than casting.  It will read the characters of the string and attempt to return an equivalent integer value.  The original object (the string) is untouched, and a new value (the int) is created.  If you "change" the original value (which is impossible in this case because strings are immutable, but for sake of argument let's assume you can) then the parsed integer would not change.  If you *casted* the object to int and *then* changed the string, they are both referencing the same value, so and changes would be reflected in both.

---

Since `SelectedValue` is a string, there's no need to cast to object and *then* call `ToString()`, so your code could be simplified to

```
int num = int.Parse(this.ddlDiscountType.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: so for - "object.ToString()" - will the compiler omit this call when generating IL code?. Or will it generate code that takes object and converts it to string..even though "object" is a string

Comment: @BobSwanson Compile it and see for yourself with ildasm.

Comment: @cubrr THanks, fixed.

Comment: i get this:   IL_0001:  ldstr      "5"
  IL_0006:  callvirt   instance string [mscorlib]System.Object::ToString()
  IL_000b:  call       int32 [mscorlib]System.Int32::Parse(string). So it looks like compiler does generate a call .ToString()

Comment: You ask for a cast, the compiler gives you a cast.  You expect the compiler to ignore your request?  Casting from `string` to `object` is _not_ unneccessary.

Comment: @BobSwanson You just told the compiler that it *isn't* a string. How and why should it second-guess your decision? You explicitly asked it to call the `Object.ToString()` virtual method, so that's what's going to happen.

Comment: @BobSwardon Same for `ToString` - you call it so the compiler will generate IL.  I think you are expecting the compiler to clean up too much of your mess...  If you know that `ToString` is unnecessary then _don't call it_.

Answer (score 2):

No, not really.

First, you need to understand the difference between runtime type information and compile-time type information.

The compile-time type of `ddlDiscountType.SelectedValue` is `string`. When you cast it to `object`, it doesn't change the runtime type, just the compile-time type - in effect, you reduced the public interface of the reference.

`ToString` is a virtual method, so as long as you don't use `new`, what happens depends on the runtime type, and has no relation to the compile-time type, as long as the method is defined in the compile-time type. Since `ToString` is defined on `Object`, there's no problem.

The compiler cannot remove the call to `ToString`, because you've explicitly said "No, this reference is not really a string. It's just an object.", so you do have to make the virtual method call. The call will use the runtime type of the reference, so you're executing `String.ToString()`, which just returns `this`. But you did all your best to *interfere* with the compiler, and the compiler isn't going to second-guess you.

Finally, `int.Parse` will parse the string and output an integer. This involves going character by character through the string, of course. Reference and value types aren't important here - it's not a cast, it's a method call like any other. The method converts a string to a number, that's it. A cast would simply throw an `InvalidCastException`, because a string is *not* an integer (though if you make your own type, you can provide your own cast methods, which can do whatever you want them to do). The compiler can't tell you that you can't cast a string to an integer, because you just said the reference isn't really a string, but rather an `object` - and an `object` *can* be casted to a `int`, if it refers to a runtime type that *is* a boxed `int`.

There's no reason to do things in such a complicated manner. Just do:

```
var number = int.Parse(ddlDiscountType.SelectedValue);
```

Spend your effort in adding proper error handling instead of doing silly rituals :)

Answer (score 0):

1: That's not correct. "Drop Down value (*string*) is **Up-casted** into *object* ".All classes in the .NET Framework are derived from *object*.(casting toward **Base class** is **up-casting**.)

2: a) Yes object is reference type.

b)*.ToString* is *object* class method(can be override by derived classes). Actually what's going on here is that *int.Parse* takes string parameter. For that you first covert that into object and then .ToString method calls.

3:Yes 3rd point is correct